# How do I connect to android server socket from ionic 2?

Tags: android, socket.io, ionic2

Can socket.io achieve this as I have not seen any example related to my configuration?

I'm streaming android camera via sockets, I want to create client using ionic 2. Have seen socket.io but fail to understand how I can use it to connect to my android server socket.

Comment: See https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/how-to-build-a-live-video-streaming-app/55493

Answer (score 0, accepted):

consider using cordova plugin like cordova-plugin-chrome-apps-sockets-tcp

https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-chrome-apps-sockets-tcp

Regards

Tom

Comment: This has given me direction but I cannot get an example to create a socket in typescript. I get cannot read property tcp chrome.socket.tcp

Comment: Hi. here some code I used work on. Not sure if it is still ok https://github.com/Tommertom/ng2sonos/blob/master/src/providers/tcp.provider.ts